# Проект Angular созданные из шаблона не запускается

Tags: visual-studio, angular

Создал новый проект в Visual Studio на основании шаблона с использованием Angular, где еще создается `SampleDataController`.

Ничего не трогая, пытаюсь его запустить и ловлю такой перечень ошибок:

> TestApp> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0] TestApp>
>   ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css TestApp> Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp'
>   TestApp> ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css TestApp> Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp'
>   TestApp> ERROR in multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0
>   ./src/main.ts TestApp> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp'
>   TestApp> ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts TestApp> Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp'
>   TestApp> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed: TestApp>   Entry
>   module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Octop  usServices\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\Clien
>   tApp': TestApp>   Error: Can't resolve 'E:\' in
>   'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\AssemblyStora 
>   ge\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp' TestApp>    TestApp>   - compiler.js:76 
>   TestApp>     [ClientApp]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16
>   TestApp>    TestApp>   - Compiler.js:300 compile TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:300:11 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Compiler.js:510 applyPluginsAsync.err TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:510:14 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Tapable.js:202 next TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   CachePlugin.js:78 Compiler. TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Compiler.js:507 compilation.seal.err TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:507:11 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Tapable.js:202 next TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   suppress-entry-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:38
>   Compilation.compilation.plugin TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[@angular]/cli/plugins/suppress-entry-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:3
>   8:17 TestApp>    TestApp>   - Tapable.js:206
>   Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Compilation.js:677 applyPluginsAsync.err TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:677:19 TestApp>    TestApp>
>   - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries TestApp>     [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Compilation.js:668 applyPluginsAsync.err TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:668:11 TestApp>    TestApp>
>   - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries TestApp>     [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46 TestApp>    TestApp>   -
>   Compilation.js:663 applyPluginsAsync.err TestApp>
>   [ClientApp]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:663:10 TestApp>    TestApp>
>   - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries TestApp>     [ClientApp]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46 TestApp>    TestApp> 
>   TestApp>        TestApp>  TestApp> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2] TestApp>
>   Request finished in 13874.1534ms 404 text/html; charset=utf-8

А в браузере красуется `Cannot GET /`.

Подскажите, что я упустил? По идее, шаблонный проект должен работать "из коробки"

Если нужна еще какая-нибудь информация, то я ее предоставлю.

npm install мне вот это выплевывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: npm install делал? и возможно потребуется еще сбилдить фронтовую часть, через ng build (возможно будет отличаться команда, так как не известно какая версия ангуляра стоит и как он интегрирован в шаблон)

Comment: Сейчас сделал и не помогло...=(

Comment: На ng build ловлю как раз ошибки, которые мне выкинул VS.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что он ругается на путь, у тебя точно есть диск E? `Can't resolve 'E:\' in 'E:!Projects!TFS\Services\TestProject\TestApp\TestApp\ClientApp'`

Comment: Да. Может быть восклицательный знак не нравится?

Comment: Вполне возможно, что в нем дело, и вроде бы после E: должен быть слеш `\`, как мне кажется

Comment: Мда... в этом дело. Перенес в корень и все успешно стартануло.

Comment: @iluxa1810 по нормальному все люди изучают angular на основе [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial), и это уже прижитая практика в течении 4х лет, идите пожалуйста по их гайду, а не занимайтесь, простите за выражение "мазохизмом" в visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, дело было в том, что в пути к проекту были восклицательные знаки "!" и это не нравилось сборщику.

После того, как перенес в корень диска, все заработало.

Вот [тут](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6723) обсуждение есть.